# plotutils: `graph` creates empty plots

Tags: windows-7, charts, gnu, gnuwin32

I'm trying to create simple plots using `graph` as described in [this tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/plotutils/manual/en/html_node/Simple-Examples.html). However, even the most basic example:

```
echo 0 0 1 1 2 0 | graph -T png > plot.png
```

produces a perfectly white 570x570 picture. The picture looks normal otherwise, having a correct PNG header and both white and black colors in the palette.

I'm using [plotutils 2.4.1](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/plotutils.htm) under Windows 7. Is it known to be broken or am I missing something silly?

PS. I've moved to `gnuplot` for the time being, but if someone has a solution/experience to share, I'm still interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your decision to switch to gnuplot. It can accomplish a wider range of actions. With the info you provided I can just try to guess that or the *png* drivers are missing or some variable is not correctly set.

Notes:

- Try to update to a more recent version
- You are using, you know, a tool developed for *nix systems. Since the png format is a proprietary one, under Linux there are compatible library that have to be installed separately.
- > **`graph` may behave differently depending on the environment in which it is invoked.**

  Moreover for this kind of tools can be important the environment variables under which the program runs.
  We can read that, among the others, the `png` file production is specifically affected by some environment variables, for example [[2](https://www.gnu.org/software/plotutils/manual/en/html_node/Simple-Examples.html)]

  > Similarly, **the BITMAPSIZE environment variable affects the operation of** graph -T X, **graph -T png**, graph -T pnm, and graph -T gif.

  Moreover [[3](https://www.gnu.org/software/plotutils/manual/en/html_node/plotfont-Environment.html)],[[4](https://www.gnu.org/software/plotutils/manual/en/html_node/graph-Environment.html#graph-Environment)]

  > **`graph` -T png** and graph -T gif, which produce output in PNG and pseudo-GIF format respectively, are affected by two environment variables. If the value of the **INTERLACE** variable is "yes", the output file will be interlaced. Also, if the value of the **TRANSPARENT_COLOR** environment variable is the name of a color that appears in the output file, that color will be treated as transparent by most applications.

---

BTW the command you provided

```
echo 0 0 1 1 2 0 | graph -T png > plot.png
```

under Linux generate the following image, that I suppose was your purpose.
[image: Your example]

The Imagemagick [[5](http://www.imagemagick.org)] `identify plot.png` answers

```
plot.png PNG 570x570 570x570+0+0 8-bit PseudoClass 2c 2.1KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

<sup>Tested with [graph (GNU plotutils) 2.6]</sup>

Comment: Yep, that graph is indeed what I expected to get. I don't think my issue is due to missing PNG libs, since the file I get is a valid PNG picture (only blank). 2.4.1 is the latest Win32 build I could find, do you have a link to a newer version I could try out?

Comment: [Plotutils site](https://www.gnu.org/software/plotutils/) that send you to [gnu mirrors](http://www.gnu.org/prep/ftp) for example [here](http://mirror.tochlab.net/pub/gnu/plotutils/), but I suppose you have to compile it... else a good overkill: a virtual machine with Linux inside (Ubuntu `sudo apt-get install plotutils`) :-)

Comment: Those look like source packages, and I don't have a build environment at hand, sorry. Looks like a solution though so I'll accept your answer (by now, I have too many scripts using `gnuplot`, it simply doesn't make sense to switch back to `graph`).

Comment: I see that it is included in [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin). Maybe you can install Cygwin... but I try to tempt you with pure Linux... under virtualbox :)